# Image uploader button not working in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am trying upload products in Magento but it is not working. I am using the Magento 1.9.2.4 version. I have updated the flash files as well as I have cleared the cache. The image button is showing but when I click them I get this error which is showing in the console.

[Not working Magento image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owgJA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Uploader js is missing.

Check:

- if `/js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js` is present
- custom layout xml? `/adminhtml/default/default/layout/main.xml`
- if /js/lib/uploader contains all 3 js files

Answer (score 0):

If you have updated or patched your magento, check if you are using any custom extension. Check if xml carries the correct js of the module.